# Compile error calling an extension method from another extension method in Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-14

When I try to call an extension method from another extension method (overloading that method) it does not compile in IntelliJ 14.1.5 and Kotlin 0.14.449

As I'm new to the language and in the reference it does not forbid to do so I would like to know:

- Is possible to call an extension method from another extension method?
- Is the syntax I'm using correct (and thus this is a bug)?
- If not, what is the correct syntax?

This is the code that does not compile:

```
fun String.replace (prefix: String, suffix: String, vararg parameters: Pair<String, String>) =
    parameters.fold(this, { result, pair -> result.replace (prefix + pair.first + suffix, pair.second) })

fun String.replace (vararg parameters: Pair<String, String>) =
    this.replace ("", "", parameters)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A lot of code in Kotlin calls one extension function from another.  The issue lies in your code, as en error.   You have two incorrect answers so far.  I'll add a new one.

Comment: Your accepted answer does not work, can you check it and edit it to be correct, or change to the answer that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I though It was a bug, I searched into the Kotlin issue tracker and found this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2079

The correct syntax to pass a `vararg` argument to another function is using an asterisk '*':

```
fun String.filter (prefix: String, suffix: String, vararg parameters: Pair<String, String>) =
    parameters.fold(this, { result, pair -> result.replace (prefix + pair.first + suffix, pair.second) })

fun String.filter (vararg parameters: Pair<String, String>) =
    this.filter("", "", *parameters)
```

Comment: This answer is not correct for Kotlin 1.0 betas+ because it causes a recursion within the first method, since the method itself overrides the version trying to be called (varargs can be omitted, so can the 3rd boolean parameter of `string.replace(string,string,boolean[optional])`)  Therefore the local function wins and is wrong.

Comment: I have to check it with my unit tests... but so far is working in my project with Kotlin 1.0 beta. Anyway, the method sign is `String.replace(vararg Pair<String, String>)`... so calling it within the same method with two strings in the first place will never resolve to the same method.

Comment: its the other form of the method that calls itself, in your answer the top one with `string, string, vararg: Pair<String, String>` calls itself on accident within the `fold` lambda.   Or maybe on purpose to recurse?  I didn't look at the logic to see if recursion made sense, but looks like you mean to call `string, string, boolean (defaulted)` version instead from the stdlib.  If not, let me know because then my answer is wrong.  Also, posting one unit test is useful since it shows intended results.  I'm testing with Kotlin 1.0 beta

Comment: Syntax error, this does not compile.  The 2nd function calls `replace` instead of `filter`.  It avoids recursion by renaming it to filter instead of keeping the name `replace` (which would cause accidental recursion in the first method).  You shouldn't silently make that "fix" without saying why.

Answer (score 2):

There are other answers, but here are more notes about what is going on and a similar solution follows that keeps the method naming, avoids recursion, and keeps `varargs` for both method signatures:

- When passing one varargs to another, you need to use the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) because varargs are received as an array, you want to convert them back into a list of parameters and spread operator does just that.
- The call inside the `fold()` lambda accidentally calls itself.  Since you call `string.replace()` with 2 parameters, which version wins?  The version `string.replace(String, String, vararg Pair<String,String>)` or `string.replace(String, String, Boolean[defaulted to false])`?  They both look the same when only called with 2 parameters.  And the local one wins and therefore you have recursion.  To force a call to the stdlib replace function, the 3rd parameter defaults to `false` so pass that value specifically so the correct method signature is found.

**Working code:**

```
fun String.replace(prefix: String, suffix: String, vararg parameters: Pair<String, String>) {
    parameters.fold(this) { result, pair ->
        // add a last parameter to differentiate what version I want called, the one with optional
        // boolean parameter last (ignoreCase: Boolean = false).  Otherwise this recurses on accident.
        result.replace(prefix + pair.first + suffix, pair.second, false)
    }
}

fun String.replace(vararg parameters: Pair<String, String>) {
    this.replace ("", "", *parameters) // add * spread operator
}
```

Comment: Excuse me Jayson, the code I posted is working. It had a problem with the name of the method, so I changed the name for other equivalent one instead making the code more complex. I would appreciate that you edit your post. Even if the code does not work at all, is the first time I see someone saying that their answer is good and the others are bad. The reader should judge that. Thanks for beeing a polite Stackoverflow user!

Comment: @jamming the problem isn't that your answer is "bad", it is that it doesn't compile and therefore is "does not work".  I left comments about the errors as well to help.  It still does not compile, you have another error.  If people see accepted answers that are invalid, and use them, it is a problem.  So I was trying to help the readers that come along later to avoid frustration.

Comment: and yes @jamming I would gladly remove the comment saying the accepted answer is broken, once it is no longer broken.  I left comments for any issue I saw there, including new ones today.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. It wasn't compiling, I should have copied the code from the project I'm using it. Now it is corrected. Thanks for taking the time to check it, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the first String.replace is recursively calling itself and the primary String.replace is never reached. Also, the vararg in the second is passed to the first as an Array> so calling the second function would never match the first.

```
fun String.replace(vararg parameters: Pair<String, String>) =
        this.replace("", "", parameters)

fun String.replace(prefix: String, suffix: String, parameters: Array<out Pair<String, String>>) =
        parameters.fold(this, { result, pair -> result.replace(prefix + pair.first + suffix, pair.second) })
```

Comment: In the second function, I try to call the first one. The arguments do not match the second function (so It should not be a recursive call). Anyway, that would be a runtime error, but I'm getting a compile error. Am I missing something?

Comment: this.replace ("", "", parameters) does not match as vararg does not translate to another vararg but an Array. Your first function gives an error saying result.replace(2) is a recursive call and that's because vararg will match on 0 and pair.first and pair.second are strings while the String.replace(1) function expects a vararg of pairs.

Comment: You shouldn't avoid the `vararg` in the 2nd function, you can add the final boolean parameter to the `replace` call within the function so that it calls the correct runtime function instead of recursing.   T